# Gentoo portage. How to find out why some particular package is installed?

Tags: gentoo, portage

Well, some packages are installed by my explicit request. These packages are listed in `/var/lib/portage/world`.

But there are packages installed because they required by some of these explicitly installed packages.

Let's say I found out that some package `aaa/bbb-1.2.3` is installed on my system. It's not in the `world` set. So there must be one or several packages in the `world` set which require (may be indirectly) the `aaa/bbb` package. How can I find out what are these packages? As a bonus I want to be able to understand why is is version `1.2.3` which is installed.

`equery (d)epends` command (installed by `app-portage/gentoolkit` package) can "list all packages directly depending on ATOM". But it's quite far from what I need.

Comment: `equery` can work this way, `equery depends bbb-1.2.3`. Besides, rare packages depend on a specific version. Most of them depend on other packages like, >aaa/bbb-1.0.0. So if some time later, bbb has a new version, say 1.2.5, then when you upgrade Gentoo, bbb will be updated to 1.2.5, because 1.2.5 is greater than 1.0.0, it still satisfy the dependency. I mean IMO understanding why this version is installed is not that meaningful.

Comment: @Bruce `equery depends bbb` produces a list of all the packages that require bbb. Even those not installed. `emerge -pv --depclean` reports only installed packages - very convenient. Update: Hmm, help says it should report only installed packages. Strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see all the packages that depend on the package (and which version they pull in) with:

```
emerge -pv --depclean <package-name>
```

Or maybe the output from

```
equery d -D <package-name>
```

is what you want: a tree of all the packages that indirectly depend on the package